# conditions on variables in optmodel in SAS

Tags: optimization, sas

I have been struggling with this problem from yesterday. I am using proc optmodel for my optimization model and I have a condition on my variable. Like I have to variables A1 and A2 and the constraint is

```
A1 = A2   if A1<0

A1 >= A2   if A1>0
```

Since A1 is also a variable SAS does not allow me to put a condition in my constraint. I am doing this:

```
var A1[C_C];
var A1[C_C];

Con test {<C1,C2> in C_C:  A1[C1,C2]<0}:
A2 [C1,C2] =A1[C1,C2];

Con test {<C1,C2> in C_C:  A1[C1,C2]>0}:
A2[C1,C2] <= A1[C1,C2];
```

and the error I get after this is: "Variables may not be used within expressions"
IS anybody has an idea about this. I already searched a lot but could not find anything.

Comment: This would make the problem nonlinear (and in a somewhat nasty form: non-differentiable). With some effort it is possible to make this linear with the addition of binary variables. Then you would need to use the mixed integer programming solver.

Comment: I think line 2 is `var A2[C_C]`. You also cannot repeat the constraint label `test`.

Comment: To give a complete answer we need a little bit more context. How to A1 and A2 contribute to the objective? Do you have any bounds on A1 or A2? E.g., could you write an expression or read data for `num a1_lb{<c1,c2> in C_C}`? To avoid the non-linearity you will probably need a bigM or some reify predicates.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be able to do this simpler?

```
proc optmodel;
  var a1,a2;
  con test:  a1 ge a2;
  con test1: a1 eq if a1 < 0 then a2 else a1;
quit;
```

I suspect there are better solutions than that, but that seems to work.

Comment: Joe, Thank yous o much for the response. I just was not sure if we can use variables in IFELASE or not. Since SAS does not allow us to use it in condition expression in constraints, I will test it though. And another concern is that in the equations you mentioned if a1 is negative for example -3 then a2<= -3 and then a2<=a2 but a2 is already less than -3 and how we can make sure that it just gets the -3. I really appreciate your help

Comment: I tested this method but still getting an error that these constraints are nonlinear. Actually my model is linear and I am using LPsolvers.

Comment: Are you sure your constraints are legal, then?  Those are nonlinear, I think, looking at them.

Comment: Probably I am missing something here. I will take a closer look. Thanks for the help